# Carrierwave not setting content_type

Tags: ruby-on-rails, carrierwave, plupload

I'm uploading an image using carrierwave. The problem I'm having is that the content_type isn't being saved to the database. I can see that the content_type is being passed into the request (as you can see below) but it doesn't seem to make it to the DB.

**upload.rb**

```
class Upload < ActiveRecord::Base
  mount_uploader :file, FileUploader
  attr_accessible :file
end
```

**file_uploader.rb**

```
require 'carrierwave/processing/mime_types'

class FileUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::MimeTypes

  storage :fog
  process :set_content_type
end
```

**uploads_controller.rb**

```
  def create
    @upload = Upload.new params[:upload]
    if @upload.save
        render :json => @upload
    end
  end
```

**schema.rb**

```
  create_table "uploads", :force => true do |t|
    t.date     "expired_at"
    t.datetime "created_at",        :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",        :null => false
    t.string   "file"
    t.text     "slug"
    t.string   "file_content_type"
  end
```

**POST request**

```
Started POST "/uploads" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-04-11 22:54:56 -0400
Processing by UploadsController#create as */*
  Parameters: {"name"=>"IMG_0004.JPG", "authenticity_token"=>"00kuSJQvgkWmCo+bWBQQzhzwC2qWdsF6T3K6DLuv0l8=", "upload"=>{"file"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fcb34399570 @original_filename="IMG_0004.JPG", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"upload[file]\"; filename=\"IMG_0004.JPG\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n", @tempfile=#<File:/var/folders/9f/zccg30y961g1kl0zc_kzkfw00000gn/T/RackMultipart20130411-90625-1je1uyu>>}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your column name to `:content_type` and it should start working.

Comment: Doesn't work. I've tried having `:content_type` as well as `:file_content_type` and neither column gets set

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem tried this in my Model file where I mounted the Uploader

```
  before_save :set_mime_type                   

    def set_mime_type
      self.mimetype = Mime::Type.lookup_by_extension(File.extname(self.cf_filename.to_s)[1..-1]) 
    end
```

Note: You need to have a mimetype field in the table